# How to handle =?windows-1251?Q? in the mail attachments?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, python-2.7, email-attachments

I receive email attachment and save it directly to blobstore:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(self.request.body)
for part in msg.walk():
  ctype = part.get_content_type()
  if ctype in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']:
    image_file = part.get_payload(decode=True)
    image_file_name = part.get_filename()
    if image_file_name[:11] == '=?KOI8-R?B?':
      image_file_name = base64.b64decode(image_file_name[11:]).decode('KOI8-R')    
    if image_file_name[:10] == '=?UTF-8?B?':
      image_file_name = base64.b64decode(image_file_name[10:])
```

How to handle Q in the filename? In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711404/how-to-get-decode-attachment-filename-with-python-email.) I asked, it has been said that Q indicates quoted-printable. But what should I do to get valid filename?

**Upd**. I've replaced the code with

```
filename_decoded = ''
for item in decode_header(filename):
    if item[1]:
        filename_decoded += item[0].decode(item[1])
    else:
        filename_decoded += item[0]
if filename_decoded != '':
    filename = filename_decoded
```

It helped me with `=?windows-1251?Q?`, but fails with normal names - `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-14: ordinal not in range(128)`. How should I fix that?

Comment: The 2nd answer on your other question was brief, but does give you a solution that is better than individually checking for the different combinations of encodings.

Comment: @Greg, that code doesn't work properly since `decode_header(filename)` returns values like  `[('screenshot_', None), ('IMG_20140712_130107_\xed\xee\xe2\xfb\xe9 \xf0\xe0\xe7\xec\xe5\xf0.jpg', 'windows-1251')]`

Comment: They look ok to me. The end bit of the 2nd one decodes to 'новый размер', which google translate tells me means 'new size' in Russian.

Comment: Thanks, @Greg. I've updated the question with new problem I faced with when used `decode_header`.