# AWS Lambda put_object function not sending file to destination s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto

I'm invoking a Lambda function to send a .csv file from an email to a destination s3 bucket which I specify in said function. The invocation is triggered by `Event type: ObjectCreatedByPut` when the email is recieved by the incoming s3 bucket.

I see from the CloudWatch logs that the function is indeed invoked as expected, but no file is ever sent to the destination s3 bucket.

Here is the incoming folder showing presence of key `mfdat0psudj12qfihankjkiindd17vftd775so01`

[image]

Here is the Lambda function;

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import urllib
import boto3
import os

import email
import base64

FILE_MIMETYPE = 'text/csv'

# destination folder
S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME = 's3-bucket/attachments/' 

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #source email bucket 
    inBucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.quote(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))


    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=inBucket, Key=key)
        msg = email.message_from_string(response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))   

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error retrieving object {} from source bucket {}. Verify existence and ensure bucket is in same region as function.'.format(key, inBucket))
        raise e
    
    #print(msg)
    
    attachment_list = []
    attachment = msg.get_payload()[1]


    try:
        #scan each part of email 
        for message in msg.get_payload():
            
            # Check filename and email MIME type
            if (message.get_filename() != None and message.content_type() == FILE_MIMETYPE):
                attachment_list.append ({'original_msg_key':key, 'attachment_filename':message.get_filename(), 'body': base64.b64decode(msg.get_payload()) })
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print ('Error processing email for CSV attachments')
        raise e
    
    # if multiple attachments send all to bucket 
    for attachment in attachment_list:

        try:
            s3.put_object(Bucket=S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME, Key=attachment['original_msg_key'] +'-'+attachment['attachment_filename'] , Body=attachment['body']) 
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print ('Error sending object {} to destination bucket {}. Verify existence and ensure bucket is in same region as function.'.format(attachment['attachment_filename'], S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME))
            raise e
            
    print(key)
    print(inBucket)
    print(S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME)
    print(message.get_filename())
    print(response)

    return event
```

And here are the logs showing successful invocation of the function.

```
Timestamp
Message
No older events at this moment. 
Retry

2020-10-25T22:05:32.093+00:00   Loading function

2020-10-25T22:05:32.208+00:00   START RequestId: 9d683660-4436-4cff-92c4-01e3ae028a67 Version: $LATEST

2020-10-25T22:05:33.326+00:00   mfdat0psudj12qfihankjkiindd17vftd775so01

2020-10-25T22:05:33.326+00:00   s3-bucket

2020-10-25T22:05:33.326+00:00   s3-bucket/attachments/

2020-10-25T22:05:33.326+00:00   None

2020-10-25T22:05:33.364+00:00   {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '4DCD1196A2C991B8', 'HostId': 'tKOE8xz3yq1gryGS+7f7u9+fdwU+buK4C/gTTzOZYZheSxXI9a1MxrggIioWttO9mwmCiwG15d0=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'tKOE8xz3yq1gryGS+7f7u9+fdwU+buK4C/gTTzOZYZheSxXI9a1MxrggIioWttO9mwmCiwG15d0=', 'x-amz-request-id': '4DCD1196A2C991B8', 'date': 'Sun, 25 Oct 2020 22:05:33 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Sun, 25 Oct 2020 22:05:31 GMT', 'etag': '"b66db710202d45a98daa0a47badf6094"', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-type': 'application/octet-stream', 'content-length': '1207346', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 25, 22, 5, 31, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'ContentLength': 1207346, 'ETag': '"b66db710202d45a98daa0a47badf6094"', 'ContentType': 'application/octet-stream', 'Metadata': {}, 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7ffba103f490>}

2020-10-25T22:05:33.366+00:00   END RequestId: 9d683660-4436-4cff-92c4-01e3ae028a67

2020-10-25T22:05:33.366+00:00   REPORT RequestId: 9d683660-4436-4cff-92c4-01e3ae028a67 Duration: 1157.42 ms Billed Duration: 1200 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 89 MB Init Duration: 413.53 ms
No newer events at this moment. 
Auto retry paused.
 
Resume
```

However when I check the `s3-bucket/attachments` the directory is empty. Interestingly `print(message.get_filename())` returns `None`.

I have checked the Lambda code for errors and have also tried using `s3.upload_file` but this does not seem to work either.

Not sure where to turn now.

Comment: Are you confident that your `for attachment in attachment_list` runs and there are any attachments?

Comment: You don't seem to have nearly enough logging in the conditional arms of your code. Is your code actually calling `s3.put_object()`?

Comment: @Marcin - Thanks for comment. There most certainly are attacments. I have verified this by examining the raw files.

Comment: @jamrod - Thanks, appreciate this is a valid observation and an oversight. I'll look to rectify.

Comment: It seems fairly likely that the attachment list is actually empty, as many people have suggested. Basic debugging techniques would have validated this very early.

Comment: @jamrod - Yes `attachement_list` is empty and this appears to be because `filename` is given as `None`. This confusing as each .csv does indeed have a filename, as verified by exploring the raw email itself.

Comment: I recommend that you dump out, or otherwise inspect, the entire message object that you get from parsing the S3 object body.

Comment: Thanks again @jarmod. If I use  `print(msg.get_payload())`, I can see, in the CloudWatch logs, the entire content of the 20k row .csv that is attached to the email that is sent to the S3 bucket. Is this what you mean by 'dump out'?

Comment: I was thinking of `print(msg)` but I have to assume that the filename for the message is coming back as None, so you'll need to understand more about the email parsing, where in the email message it should get filename from, and why that is not present in the file you're downloading from S3. Maybe research Python email attachment parsing some more ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711404/how-to-get-decode-attachment-filename-with-python-email)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223659/discussion-between-jimiclapton-and-jarmod).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having improved my error handling and exploring the methods of the mail library, I was able to confirm that `message.content_type()` is incorrect and the correct method is infact `message.get_content_type()`. The implication of using the incorrect method was that the condition `for message in msg.get_payload():...` was not able to evaluate and output anything, hence the `None` returned for `print(message.get_filename())` and therefore the blank list for `attachement_list`.

Correct statement below for reference of anyone looking to replicate this functionality with Lambda or elsewhere.

```
try:
        #scan each part of email 
        for message in msg.get_payload():
            
            # Check filename and email MIME type
            if  (message.get_content_type() == FILE_MIMETYPE and message.get_filename() != None):
                attachment_list.append ({'original_msg_key':key, 'attachment_filename':message.get_filename(), 'body': base64.b64decode(message.get_payload()) })
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print ('Error processing email for CSV attachments')
        raise e
```

Thanks for all contributions and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You’re setting `S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME = 's3-bucket/attachments/'` and using this as the argument for`Bucket` in the `put_object` call. This won’t work, as a bucket name cannot contain slashes (`/`).

The “folder” must be part of the key. In fact, S3 doesn’t have any folders as it’s not a file system. Folders from an actual file system are translated into prefixes as part of the object’s key.

Try changing your function in the following way:

```
...
S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME = 's3-bucket'
...
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME, 
    Key='attachments/' + attachment['original_msg_key'] + '-' + attachment['attachment_filename'] , 
    Body=attachment['body']
)
...
```

Having that said, I suspect that `attachment_list` turns out to be empty and `put_object()` isn’t even being executed. Please add some logging around the `if` statement that is supposed to add attachments to the list and the `for` loop that iterates over the items in `attachment_list`. There might be a bug hidden there.

Comment: Thanks, @Dennis Traub for the explanation. I will try this.
Question however, should it be `...Key='/attachments/' + attachment...` as opposed to  `...Key='/attachment/' + attachment...` since the former reflects the name of the destination within the bucket?

Comment: Good catch, my mistake. You’re completely right, it’s supposed to be Key=‘/attachments/‘ + ...

Comment: Ok, made the changed and deployed but seems to have not made a discernible difference but I really appreciate your input and wasn't aware a bucket name couldn't contain slashes.

Comment: Happy to help. In order to resolve the underlying issue, I’d recommend doing what has already been suggested in another answer: Add more logging to understand if put_object is even called. The fact that it didn’t throw an error with the faulty bucket name indicates that it doesn’t even execute that pieces of code.

Comment: I’ve added an additional suggestion to my answer. Maybe that helps.

Comment: `attachment_list` is indeed empty - further debugging required!

Comment: The key should be of the form `folder/filename.png`, rather than `/folder/filename.png` with leading forward slash. The latter will yield what appears to be a blank top-level folder name (not what you want).

Answer (score 1):

your `print(message.get_filename())` seems to indicate the filename is `None` and you have a specific case in your loop that says `message.get_filename() != None` so it looks like there are no valid attachments.

I would add more debugging around what messages are in the payload and then double check your assumptions about what a valid filename, mimetype, etc are to be and if you have the right conditions setup.

Comment: Thanks @JD D - The filename of the attachment is certainly not `None`. Exploring the raw email shows that the .csv file does indeed have a filename, which I was expecting to see using `print(message.get_filename())`